# How to extract foursquare2 gem results (Hashie::Mash)

Tags: ruby, api, rubygems, foursquare

I'm facing a problem while trying to extract fields of foursquare2 gem response. Here's my code:

```
   require 'foursquare2'

   client = Foursquare2::Client.new(:client_id => 'XYZ', :client_secret => 'XYZ')

   tips = client.venue_tips('4d169843b15cb1f7f4c4ae21')
```

And then I got the result:

```
#<Hashie::Mash count=8 items=[#<Hashie::Mash     canonicalUrl="https://foursquare.com/item/4f689747e4b04ab624cce6d3" createdAt=1332254535   done=#<Hashie::Mash count=1> id="4f689747e4b04ab624cce6d3" lang="pt" likes=#<Hashie::Mash count=2 groups=[#<Hashie::Mash count=2 items=[#<Hashie::Mash bio="" contact=#<Hashie::Mash> firstName="Pedro" gender="male" homeCity="Recife, Brasil" id="19761425" lastName="T." photo="https://is1.4sqi.net/userpix_thumbs/G5R14BT031K2B2AX.jpg" tips=#<Hashie::Mash count=25>>, #<Hashie::Mash bio="" contact=#<Hashie::Mash> firstName="Nat\u00E1lia" gender="female" homeCity="Recife, Brasil" id="12706383" lastName="S."
photo="https://is0.4sqi.net/userpix_thumbs/UF0Q0OZFWNQLXRFG.jpg" tips=#<Hashie::Mash count=1>>] type="others">] summary="2 likes"> text="Nova padaria com bons  produtos, destaque para as formadas de p\u00E3o \u00E0 tarde."
```

I'd like to have something as **tips.firstName** to get these values, but it doesn't work. Should I prefer the REST API?!

Thank you in advance, guys.

**Edited after comments**

The solution I did following the suggestion provided:

```
tips.groups[0].items.each{|i| puts i.firstName}
```

But it's not working. I just got the error: data_scraping_fq.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is? In your question, you have retrieved a list of tips, and e.g. `tips.items[0].firstName` should return "Pedro" . . .

Comment: @NeilSlater Yes, the problem is it should, but don't. And this is the thing: I don't manage to get the data inside of Hashie::Mash. I'd like to get the values of each field. Hope it helps.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description. You'll need to [edit] and be much more specific; we can't see your screen or read your mind from here.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for your advice. I included the error message right after "it's not working". Anyway, I'm trying to figure how I could be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

`tips.firstName` won't work when you're using the [venues/tips](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/tips) endpoint. Take a look at the JSON response when you use the Foursquare API explorer and you'll see that to get the tip submitter's first name, you need to look at `tips.items

Comment: Thank you @octopi. I tried to do what you suggested but still without any positive results. I did "tips.groups[0].items.each{|i| puts i.firstName}" but seems wrong. Thank you anyway, I'll keep trying.

Comment: @gfm tips.items.each, I am not sure where you are getting "groups" from, it is not necessary.